# Probability of find exacly $k - 1$ elements of certain type in at least one group of the ${n}\choose{k}$ possible groups

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to find the probability of data leak of a security protocol. In this protocol I have $n$ users in groups of size $k$ with $k < n$. Also, $m$ of these users are malicious users, with $k - 1 \leq m < n$ and the rest $h = n - m$ are honest users. I want to know, assuming groups are formed completely at random, what is the probability that at least one of those groups have exactly $k - 1$ malicious users and one honest user. I am not interested in groups with less than $k - 1$ malicious users because the protocol guarantees the security in this case, and I am not interested either in the case of groups with $k$ malicious users because as all would be malicious, there's nobody to protect. I call a group with exactly $k - 1$ malicious users a risk group.

I thought that it would be something like:

$$
P = \frac{\text{Number of possible risk groups} \times \text{Number of honest users}}{\text{Number of all possible groups}}
$$

$$
= \frac{{{m}\choose{k - 1}}h}{{n}\choose{k - 1}}
$$

but it turns out that it does not work for the following simple example with $n = 6, k = 3, m = 5, h = 1$:

$$
P = \frac{1{5 \choose 2}}{6 \choose 2} = \frac{10}{15} = 0.666
$$

In this example the probability of finding a group with exactly $k - 1$ malicious users should be 1 because as there is only one honest user, necessarily this user must belong to a malicious group.

Can you help me suggesting me what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Can the groups overlap? If not, are you assuming that $n$ is a multiple of $k$?

Comment: No, groups can't be overlapped, each user belongs to only one group and we can assume that $n$ is multiple of $k$ even though in practice could exists groups with $k + 1$ users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that there is at least one honest user at risk is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^h (-1)^{i-1}\binom{h}{i}
\frac{\binom{m}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}\times 
\frac{\binom{m-(k-1)}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1-k}{k-1}}\times 
\frac{\binom{m-2(k-1)}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1-2k}{k-1}}\times \dots \times 
\frac{\binom{m-i(k-1)}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1-ik}{k-1}}.
$$

You can prove this using the principle of inclusion exclusion. Number the honest users from $1$ to $h$. Let $E_i$ be the event that the $i^\text{th}$ honest user is at risk, for each each $i\in \{1,\dots,h\}$. To find the probability of at least one of the events in $E_1,\dots,E_h$ occurring, you need to use the principle of inclusion exclusion to account for the overlapping nature of these events:
\begin{align}
P(E_1\cup \dots \cup E_h)
&= \sum_{i=1}^h (-1)^{i-1} 
\sum_{1\le j_1<j_2<\dots<j_i\le h }P(E_{j_1}\cap  \dots \cap E_{j_i})
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^h (-1)^{i-1}
\binom{h}i P(E_1\cap E_2\cap \dots \cap E_i).
\tag{$\text{symmetry}$}
\end{align}
All that remains is to find $P(E_1\cap E_2\cap \dots \cap E_i)$, which is the probability that the honest users numbered $1$ to $i$ are all at risk.

- The probability that the first honest user is at risk $\frac{\binom{m}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}$. This is because there are $\binom{m}{k-1}$ ways to choose $k-1$ malicious users to be in the group with that honest user, out of a total of $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ to choose $k-1$ other users to be in that group.
- Conditional on the first honest user being at risk, the probability that the second honest user is at risk is $$\frac{\binom{m-(k-1)}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1-k}{k-1}}.$$This is because there are now only $m-(k-1)$ malicious users to choose from, and only $n-1-k$ other remaining in total.
- Continuing with this pattern, the probability that the first $i$ honest users are all at risk is exactly
  $$
  \frac{\binom{m}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}\times 
  \frac{\binom{m-(k-1)}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1-k}{k-1}}\times 
  \frac{\binom{m-2(k-1)}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1-2k}{k-1}}\times \dots \times 
  \frac{\binom{m-i(k-1)}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1-ik}{k-1}}.
  $$

Comment: I finally understand you answer and I think is right, thank you so much.